# How to automatically confirm all fastlane commands with "Yes"

Tags: xcode, jenkins, fastlane

I want to execute fastlane command to update project signing.

```
fastlane run update_project_codesigning path:"PROJECT.xcodeproj"
```

For the first time it always asks for confirmation "Yes" or "No" to update xcode xcode format:

```
[18:50:33]: Updating the Automatic Codesigning flag to disabled for the given project '/Users/user/.jenkins/workspace/PROJECT-IOS/platforms/ios/PROJECT.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj'
[18:50:33]: Seems to be a very old project file format
[18:50:33]: PLEASE BACKUP ALL FILES before doing this.
Proceed with upgrade to xcode8 format? (y/n)
```

In terminal I can do

```
yes | fastlane run update_project_codesigning path:"PROJECT.xcodeproj"
```

and it works.

But on Jenkins it doesn't work. As far as I understood, Jenkins doesn't support interactive commands.

How can I automatically set "YES" confirmation for all fastlane commands?

Answer (score 0):

I found out how to automatically confirm changing the xcode format.
Just set the `FL_PROJECT_SIGNING_FORCE_UPGRADE` environment variable to 1 or true.

I did:

```
export FL_PROJECT_SIGNING_FORCE_UPGRADE=1
fastlane run update_project_codesigning path:"PROJECT.xcodeproj"
```

and it works